# Delete Mail using camel without the consumer

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-camel-mail

Hy all,

in the software I'm developing, I have different camel routes that work on data, that is (in this case) loaded from an imap server using the camel-mail component.
Each of those routes does something with the data and then gives the data to the next route. They are dynamically configured at runtime.
In between those routes is an embedded ActiveMQ server which is used by each route to load the data from and save the data to (for the next route to pick it up).

Because of this structure I'm having a special case with the camel-mail consumer.
When loading a mail and sending it to the first ActiveMQ queue, it is immediatelly deleted/marked as read (depending on the settings on the mail consumer), but the actual processing of the mail has not concluded yet, as the next routes still have to process it.

This is a simplified view:

```
from("imaps://imap.server.com?...")
  // Format mail in a way the other routes understand
  .to("activemq:queue1"); // After this the mail is delete on the imap server

from("activemq:queue1")
  // do some processing
  .to("activemq:queue2");

from("activemq:queue2")
  // Do some final processing
  .to("..."); // NOW the mail should be delete on the imap server
```

This issue is even more a problem with the error handling I do.
Ever route in this "chain" sends failed exchanges to a deadLetterQueue on the ActiveMQ server. This way there is one error handling route, which picks up the failed exchanges and deals with them, on matter where it crashed.
In case there is a problem I want the email on the imap server to be handled differently (maybe even do nothing an try again on the next poll)

As camels InOut MEP returns the exchange to the (mail)consumer when the route ends i.e. when the exchange is given to the queue, I can't use the consumer to delete the mails after the whole process has ended.
Unfortunatelly I also don't see a delete option on the mail producer (which makes sense I guess, because its not how imap works).
I could also use smtp for this if thats necessary.

Does anybody have an idea how I could achieve this using no other connector then the camel component to connect to the mail server?

Greets and thanks in advance
Chris

**Edit:**
Adding the parameter "*exchangePattern=InOut*" to the jms queues (*.to("activemq:queue1?exchangePattern=InOut")*) lets the mail component wait for the whole process to finish.
The problem with that is, that we lose the big advantage with ActiveMQ that all routes are independent of each other. This is important so we are don't run into issues with consuming the mail when a later route takes a long time to process, which is very likely to happen.
So idealy we find a solution, where the mail is deleted without any component waiting for something to finish

Comment: Are you using activemq just for transferring data between routes ?

Comment: Basically. Instead of using the "direct" endpoint to have the routes pass the message on to the next route, there is always an activemq queue in between